# Problema con varios && en jFrame

Tags: java, jframe

tengo el siguiente código donde he de controlar si una comida lleva x ingredientes, la cosa es que si cumple los ingredientes pero seleccionas alguno mas tambien te lo da por bueno dado que el codigo es el siguiente

```
if(radioLentejas.isSelected()){
        if(chkChorizo.isSelected() && chkMorcilla.isSelected() && chkGarbanzos.isSelected() && chkZanahoria.isSelected()){
            lblResultado.setText("Correcto");
        }else{
            lblResultado.setText("Equivocado!");
        }
    }
```

mi duda sería si hay alguna forma de controlar que solo coja esos elementos y ninguno mas, porque por ejemplo si seleccionara esos elementos mas alguno mas tambien lo daria por bueno

Como respuesta, muchas gracias a @Jakala, JFrame trae el siguiente evento para cuando cambia el estado, añadiendo un contador será suficiente para luego comprobar si el número de checks es correcto:

```
private void chkPimentonItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                             
        if(chkPimenton.isSelected()){
            countChecked++;
        }else if(!chkPimenton.isSelected()){
            countChecked--;
        }
        lblResultado.setText(String.valueOf(countChecked));
    }
```

Comment: Puedes probar con algun tipo de *mascara* tal que `[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0]` donde cada `1` representa qué ingrediente ha seleccionado. y tienes otra para cada receta. Entonces comparas una con otra para determinar si están marcados los que deben ser. El caso es ordenar los ingredientes de una manera cronologica por ejemplo, asi si en el futuro tienes nuevos ingredientes, no hace falta refactorizar mucho las mascaras guardadas si no añadir ceros al final.

Comment: @lois6b estoy probando con ItemStateChanged, de forma que si cambia el estado a selected sume 1 al contador, el problema es que tengo que controlar todas las cajas, y a tu comentario es que no he trabajado con mascaras

Comment: Lo de máscaras no es algo si no una idea. En este caso puedes usar un string formado por `0`'s y `1`'s o un array ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dado que la "formula" de tu receta es esa, una opcion seria que añadieras el resto de ingredientes posibles pero negados. Por ej, ti tuvieras tambien lechuga y queso, podrias hacer:

```
if(radioLentejas.isSelected()){
        if(chkChorizo.isSelected() && chkMorcilla.isSelected() && chkGarbanzos.isSelected() && chkZanahoria.isSelected() && !chkLechuga.isSelected() && !chkQueso.isSelected()){
            lblResultado.setText("Correcto");
        }else{
            lblResultado.setText("Equivocado!");
        }
    }
```

Otra forma (esta te la explico, no se hacerlo exacto en JFrame) es que, de alguna manera busques el numero total de ingredientes que tienes marcados (un count de todos los checks). Si ese count es distinto al de tu receta, seria que hay mas ingredientes añadidos y es erroneo:

```
total_checks = get_checks();  // esto es un ejemplo, hay que modificarlo para JFrame
if(radioLentejas.isSelected()){
        if(chkChorizo.isSelected() && chkMorcilla.isSelected() && chkGarbanzos.isSelected() && chkZanahoria.isSelected() && total_checks == 5){
            lblResultado.setText("Correcto");
        }else{
            lblResultado.setText("Equivocado!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: me gusta más la segunda opción

Comment: Muchas gracias, ni por asomo se me habia pasado por la cabeza controlar la cantidad de checks, si te parece te edito la pregunta cuando lo consiga en jFrame

Comment: Como bien había comentado @lois6b elimino mi respuesta, además lo de contar checks me parece buena idea (aplausos)